# Get Abbrevation From a string

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

How would I get the accroyn  letter of the string

for example i have a string

"Location1 Location2 Wall21" or may have "loc loc wal2012";

I need Output looks like

loc1loc2wal21 and loclocwal2012

means to say first 3 letter of a word and all numeric words with that string

I used this

```
echo preg_replace('~\b(\w{3})|.~', '$1', $s);
```

But it gives only 3 words not all numeric charcter.

AnyBody have idea how to resolve this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then only include letters, and take out that `|.`:

```
echo preg_replace('~\b(\p{L}{3})\p{L}*|\s~', '$1', $s);
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/URFTry)

Comment: it doesn't show numeric letter i need all numeric letters too

Comment: @Rashmi: Updated, I didn't see the `|.` part.